# Why is the div not aligning correctly, vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this ([link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q9b0.jpg)):

[image]

And I have achieved this ([link to full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfbOW.jpg)):

[image]

If you notice, the div that is in right to the left navigation, is not displaying at top, but at bottom. It should start displaying right below the top navigation.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_02.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="top-nav">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_01.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_02.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_03.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_04.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_05.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_06.png" alt="">
            <img src="images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_05_07.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left-nav">
            <div id="left-nav-head">STORE CATEGORIES</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
            <div class="left-nav-link">Category Name</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-right">
            item title may go here item title may go here 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
img{ display:block; }
#container { background-color: #000; width: 100%; overflow:hidden; }
#header { width: 1010px; margin:0 auto 65px auto; }
#logo { width: 1010px; margin-bottom: 13px; }
#top-nav img { float:left; }
#content { width: 1010px; margin:0 auto; }
#left-nav { border: solid 1px #e56bae; width: 188px; }
#left-nav-head { background-image:url(images/parislane-ebay-listing-template2_15.png); height: 22px; padding-left:9px; vertical-align:middle; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color:#000; font-weight:bold; padding-top: 10px; }
.left-nav-link { background-color:#292929; border-bottom: solid 1px #4b4b4b; padding:9px 9px 7px 9px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color:#fff; }
#content-right { width:805px; margin-left:15px; float:right; color:#fff; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Currently you've specified the `width` of `#content-right` in pixels, So in smaller screen it'll break down to next line. If this is not the issue, Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something similar demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the divs float left.

```
#nav-left, #content-right{
float:left;
}
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3EJ6k/

block elements take up a full row even if 2 in succession have widths that should theoretically fit side by side, they wont do so unless floated.